# Gracefully restarting Service Fabric Application while in Production to reflect an update to the Data Package

Tags: c#, .net, azure-service-fabric, application-restart

I have a working C#/.NET application designed for Azure Service Fabric. The application uses Data Package and Config Package files, which are read in the constructor of the Stateless Service Fabric application during initialization. Together the files provide information that enables the application to create multiple infinitely long running Tasks in the RunAsync method of the app.

Now say, there is an update to the Data Package file after the Application has already been in production for a long time, say hours/days or more. I want the application to read the Data Package and Config Package from scratch and restart from the initialization steps performed in the constructor of the Stateless application.

After looking around I found the "RestartDeployedCodePackageAsync" method, which needs to be invoked as follows:

```
await client.FaultManager.RestartDeployedCodePackageAsync(applicationName, selector, CompletionMode.Verify);
```

This is described in detail on this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-testability-workload-tests

Should I use this method to achieve what I am looking to do? Is it the best method to do so?

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you should perform a service upgrade deployment with just the configuration changes.
Use the same structure as a regular package, but without code, with just the new data & config files.

More info [here](https://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/updating-azure-service-fabric-settings) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-application-upgrade-tutorial-powershell).